# Hangfire with multiple servers

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I am working on an application where I have multiple servers on different machines doing long operations for me. There is a windows service running on those machines written with hangfire/topshelf. Only one operation can run at a time per machine. Additionally I want to do some status check and cleaning jobs periodically *on each server*, so I can't just queue them as jobs.

Is there a way to do that in hangfire? Also, is there a way to send a follow-up job to the same server as an earlier job?

ADD-ON: I know one possibility would be to add another hangfire layer: Make each of the services a hangfire client with own DB and serve themselves, and then schedule recurring jobs for them, but that seems awfully complicated - especially when scaling out and adding servers.

Comment: Hangfire is implemented as a queue, and will only assign one server per job, so no need to worry about that. However, there is no ability to establish affinity to a particular server AFAIK. You'd have to coordinate within your app, perhaps using a distributed cache or key/value layer.

Comment: @HackedByChinese: I know that it is only one server per job. I need it the other way around, one job per server. That I can do with the WorkerCount. But then there are jobs I want to periodically run on every server, because they do cleanup on the server ...

Answer (score 0):

If your task is to run some scheduled task on each server, I think, the best option is to implement it yourself, Hangfire don't support events handling, only command handling. I think, you reached the point of Hangfire possibilities and need to switch to more powerful and general tool.

For events and their handling you can use other systems, for example RabbitMQ. You just specify event generator and subscribe all your machines for this event.

Comment: Submit/Listen to events across the internet? The machines are not in a local network!

Comment: They can be everywhere. Very concept of events and their handling is implemented in Rabbit. So, yes, you can subscribe across internet. Read this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html

Comment: I'm not sure I want to implement another external tool at the moment, but thanks for the suggestion! If I find no way with hangfire, I might be forced to.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but the way we handle this sort of thing is just to write a simple console application and schedule it with Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably resolved this by now, but

1 - one job per server - as you have it - worker count - probably the best as you can have multiple queues per server and the filters won't help you there.

2 - should the cleanup run after each processing job?
if yes, you can create the cleanup job from within your process job execution (ok maybe not perfect design but it works just fine) and assign to a queue on the same server, just add some logic in filters to ensure processing job is followed by a cleanup job and you're sorted.

alternatively you can use Continuation jobs (as on the site https://www.hangfire.io/) - Haven't used these but sounds like it might do the trick.

if you just want to periodically run the cleanup code then just schedule the job as recurring on each of the servers